# Storing files based on months

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to save log files to their respected months. i.e. if the month starts with "2018-10" then save to "October" and so on. Kinda lost, any help would be great!

```
time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
time = time[0:10]
date = str(time)

for month in date:
    if '2018-10' == 'October':
    os.rename(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\{date}_log', 
    f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\October')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the month full name with:

```
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%B')
```

Then save your logs using that value.